# Regular Expression in EMEditor

Tags: regex, regular-expressions, search-and-replace

I am trying to make a simple find > replace regular expression. This does work fine in https://regexr.com/ to find this comment below. However the editor I use is EMEditor that i try to make a find and replace trough files and subdirectories. However even though it finds the string in the regexr.com, it does not find it in the EMEditor search. Does anyone have a idea what the issue is?

Here is the regular expression I use:

```
\<\!\-\-.{120,150}\-\-\>
```

Here is what I try to find:

```
<!-- Mirrored from domainname.com/Showcase_to_the_world.html by HTTrack Website Copier/3.x [XR&CO'2014], Mon, 08 Mar 2021 11:12:38 GMT -->
```

If I copy my string into regexr.com and use the above regular expression it does find it, but if I do a find using EMEditor with regular expression on, than it does not find anything. I am not sure what the issue would be. Any advice would be very welcome.

Thank you all for the assistance on this.

Answer (score 0):

I had figured it out and I want to ensure I give some advice to anyone that might have the same issue. The problem in EMEditor was that it did not like the `\<` for some reason. I am not sure why. However, once I changed my statement to:

```
\-\-.{120,150}\-\-
```

This worked fine. Of course it found only:

```
-- Mirrored from domainname.com/Showcase_to_the_world.html by HTTrack Website Copier/3.x [XR&CO'2014], Mon, 08 Mar 2021 11:12:38 GMT --
```

So I did a find replace for this and than had the <!> left. So after this I could do a standard find/replace in files where I was looking for the remaining <!> and replaced this.